# Freeing all the heap at exit

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, heap-memory

My code is riddled by snippets like these ones:

```
if (!(row = malloc(reading_size))) memory_error();
if (!(unknowns = calloc(terms, sizeof(*unknowns)))) {
    free(row);
    memory_error();
}

// ...

if (!(unknowns = realloc(unknowns, (terms += TERMS) * sizeof(*unknowns)))) {
    free(row);
    free(unknowns);
    memory_error();
}
```

It clutters the code quite a bit. Now, is it worth it? If memory allocation fails I don't really see the need of freeing some other variables.

By the way, the function `memory_error()` is nothing special:

```
void memory_error(void) {
    puts("Could not allocate memory.");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Alternatively, is there a solution to free all the heap at exit? It's been suggested to me that I do the following:

- write wrappers around `malloc()`, `calloc()` and `realloc()`, to handle their failures inside my wrappers;
- keep track of the memory allocated in a flexible data structure
- register a function with `atexit()` which would clean up all the memory allocated (making use of the above data structure).

I'm not really sure about this, since all the freeing would be done at exit, so it is pointless anyway. As I understand it, freeing memory is important if you do it as soon as you don't need that memory.

What's the best course of action in this scenario?

Comment: You could build yourself one of these: http://www.hboehm.info/gc/

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought about a GC but I think it would be an overkill for my project. It's a command line utility, so probably memory leaks aren't happening, but I was interested in the best practices.

Comment: Personally I'd just keep the program flow clear and correct, as you currently do. You *could* consider allocating an array of `struct`s if appropriate.

Comment: if you exit on the first memory allocation error anyway, you don't need to bother about freeing all the memory of those calls that succeeded. 

This will be taken care of by the OS anyway (if you are on a platform that has one, that is).

Comment: Freeing all the heap at exit，gild the lily

Answer (score 2):

error recovery is sometimes best handled with the `goto` statement.

```
if (!(row = malloc(reading_size))) {
    goto error_row;
}
if (!(unknowns = calloc(terms, sizeof(*unknowns)))) {
    goto error_unknowns1;
}

// ...

if (!(unknowns = realloc(unknowns, (terms += TERMS) * sizeof(*unknowns)))) {
    goto error_unknowns2;
}

error_unknowns2:
    free(unknowns);
error_unknowns1:
    free(row);
error_row:
    memory_error();
```

The `goto` statement is used in case of failure to cause the unregistration of only the facilities that had been successfully registered before things went bad.

Comment: That's not a bad idea at all, but you might want to explain why the frowned-upon `goto` is acceptable in this circumstance. Quite often, using a `goto` in an answer is a sure way of getting downvoted.

Comment: It's because `goto` is easy to misuse. Or to mislabel: The recent OpenSSL fail was due to the use of goto to a misleading label (the label was named `fail` but didn't actually fail the function, as it only performed clean-up). But in C, it's a good substitute for C++ destructors.

Comment: `goto` is alowed everywhere where structured programming concepts do not support the situation. That is often the case in error handling. Another point where `goto` is allowed is in the exit of a nested loop.